# How can make the smoothed vtk mesh vertices distribute evenly?

Tags: vtk

After smoothing the contour constructed by MatchingCubes with below codes,

```
contour=vtk.vtkMarchingCubes()
smoother = vtk.vtkWindowedSincPolyDataFilter()
```

The result seem like below. Some vertices are unevenly distributed. Is there any method to make them more 'evenly segmented'?

[image]

Comment: Honestly those vertices look pretty good to me.  Straight out of marching cubes don't look so even, and if you run decimation on the mesh they'd look even more uneven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other users looking for an answer from this post:

C++ using VTK
https://github.com/valette/ACVD

python using pyvista / VTK
https://github.com/pyvista/pyacvd
($ pip install pyacvd)

Example using pyacvd from a function that converts a simpleITK binary image to a VTK polydata:

```py
import numpy as np
import SimpleITK as sitk
import vtk
from vtk.util import numpy_support
import pyvista as pv
import pyacvd

def sitk2vtk(self, sitk_pointer, nb_points=None):    
    numpy_array = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(sitk_pointer)
    size = list(sitk_pointer.GetSize())
    origin = list(sitk_pointer.GetOrigin())
    spacing = list(sitk_pointer.GetSpacing())
    label = numpy_support.numpy_to_vtk(num_array=numpy_array.ravel(), deep=True, array_type=vtk.VTK_FLOAT)
    
    # Convert the VTK array to vtkImageData
    img_vtk = vtk.vtkImageData()
    img_vtk.SetDimensions(size)
    img_vtk.SetSpacing(spacing)
    img_vtk.SetOrigin(origin)
    img_vtk.GetPointData().SetScalars(label)

    MarchingCubeFilter = vtk.vtkDiscreteMarchingCubes()   
    MarchingCubeFilter.SetInputData(img_vtk)
    MarchingCubeFilter.GenerateValues(1, 1, 1)   
    MarchingCubeFilter.Update() 

    if nb_points:        
        # wrapper vtk polydata to pyvista polydata        
        pv_temp = pv.PolyData(MarchingCubeFilter.GetOutput())        
        cluster = pyacvd.Clustering(pv_temp)        
        cluster.cluster(int(nb_points))        
        remesh = cluster.create_mesh()        
        remesh_vtk = vtk.vtkPolyData()        
        remesh_vtk.SetPoints(remesh.GetPoints())        
        remesh_vtk.SetVerts(remesh.GetVerts())        
        remesh_vtk.SetPolys(remesh.GetPolys())        
        return remesh_vtk    
    else:        
        return MarchingCubeFilter.GetOutput()
```

Some examples for ITK/VTK reader/writer/converter: https://github.com/guatavita/IOTools

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28512413)

Comment: @JinLee Sorry, I have made edits by providing a python function.